# TypeError: int() argument must be a string during migrating django model

Tags: django, django-models

I am facing a problem after I add a new field as a foreign key:

In the beginning, My models  was this:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

Later, I have added a foreign-key field for author and my models these belelow:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

After i add new foreign key, i run `pythion3 manage.py makemigrations` command and it guides me to insert so `1` or `2`, I insert `1` and then add `timezone.now()`
it was the guide: [image]

later, i tried to run `python3 manage.py migrate` command, but it throws me following error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'
```

I know i can fix it just using `null=True`, `blank=Tru`e in author field but i dont need to keep this field null

I am not getting how fix this error, can anyone help me to fix this error? Even i am not getting how add new foregin key fields after i run a few makemigrations,

Can anyone suggest me in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `author` field is a non `nullable` field. Which means for existing `Book` objects in your database you need to specify a `foreignkey` value for the `author` field that points to an existing `Author` object.

You are getting the error because the `ForeignKey` field needs an `integer` but you are passing a `datetime` object

Making the field `nullable` will resolve the issue:

```
author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

If you do not want the field to be `nullable` you will have to pass a once of default value. This value needs to be a `pk` value of an existing `Author` object and not a `datetime` object.

Comment: No, IT cant be null, this is must have field

Comment: Read my answer again. Like I said if the field cant be `null` you will have to set the value to a `PK` of an existing `Author` object and not a `datetime`. Another approach is to role back all migrations and creating a new initial one. Which I wont recommend unless this is a new project with no data.

Comment: Even i am unable to add new author, coz, i couldnt yet migrate it because of the error,

Comment: Do this in two separate steps. Add the `Author` model `makemigrations`, create an author,  then add the `ForeignKey` field and `makemigrations` again.

Comment: Thank for you suggestion but let me know, is it good practice?

Comment: Best practise would be to have your database design ready before you start developing it. Unfortunately in your case (unless you do a roleback to before you added the `Book` model) you will have to run two migrations. This is however not an issue.